# Xcode on Mac App Store requires additional storage even though I have more than enough?

Tags: mac, xcode, mac-app-store

[image]
As you can see, when I try to install Xcode 9.0.1, I'm shown an error that says I need an additional 5.6 GB of free space on my drive, yet I have 10.98 GB available, and the App Store lists Xcode as only requiring 5.46 GB of space.

So why can't I download it?

Comment: You must have enough to download the package and then extract it.  You don’t have enough free space to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that problem came from a combination of two issues. The first issue (I think) was that the download of Xcode had previously failed, leaving some extraneous files on my drive. The second issue is that I had just finished deleting large files from my drive, and it had yet to recognize all the extra storage space.

The solution was to restart my computer and retry the download.